# How to extract rows of a data frame between two characters

Tags: r

I've got some poorly structured data I am trying to clean. I have a list of keywords I can use to extract data frames from a CSV file. My raw data is structured roughly as follows:
There are 7 columns with values, the first columns are all string identifiers, like a credit rating or a country symbol (for FX data), while the other 6 columns are either a header like a percentage change string (e.g. +10%) or just a numerical value. Since I have all this data lumped together, I want to be able to extract data for each category. So for instance, I'd like to extract all the rows between my "credit" keyword and my "FX" keyword in my first column. Is there a way to do this in either base R or dplyr easily?

eg.

```
df %>%
    filter(column1 = in_between("credit", "FX"))
```

Sample dataframe:

```
row 1: c('random',-1%', '0%', '1%, '2%')
row 2: c('credit', NA, NA, NA, NA)
row 3: c('AAA', 1,2,3,4)
...
row n: c('FX', '-1%', '0%', '1%, '2%')
```

And I would want the following output:

```
row 1: c('credit', -1%', '0%', '1%, '2%')
row 2: c('AAA', 1,2,3,4)
...
row n-1: ...
```

Comment: I could also do this in python but I figured R would be easier.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example as it is not clear.  Also expected output would be useful

Comment: I added a small example.

Comment: can you use `dput` to show the example as it will be easier to copy and check

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you could do something like

```
start <- which(df$column1 == "credit")
end   <- which(df$column1 == "FX")
df[start:(end-1), ]
```

Of course this won't work if "credit" or "FX" is in the column more than once.

Comment: Can we generalize this? We can get all start/end points using `dividers = which(df$column1 %in% keywords == TRUE)`. If there are n divider indices I would need n-1 data frames to be outputted.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to split a data frame into multiple data frames?  Probably would be easier to add a group column then using `group_by()` or `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using what Brian suggested:

```
in_between <- function(df, start, end){
    return(df[start:(end-1),])
}
```

Then loop over the indices in

```
dividers = which(df$column1 %in% keywords == TRUE)
```

And save the function outputs however one would like.

```
lapply(1:(length(dividers)-1), function(x) in_between(df, start = dividers[x], end = dividers[x+1]))
```

This works. Messy data so I still have the annoying case where I need to keep the offset rows.

Comment: There's just the annoying case that the first row might look like `c('random',-1%', '0%', '1%, '2%')` and doing it this way we would exclude that first row, which we do not want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish but does this do what you need it to?

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  x = sample(LETTERS[1:10]),
  y = rnorm(10),
  z = runif(10)
)

start <- c("C", "E", "F")

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(start = x %in% start,
         group = cumsum(start))

split(df2, df2$group)
```